# Map frequently changing JSON value to corresponding element in Scala

Tags: scala, lift-json

I have a JSON value like

```
{
    "valType": "Integer",
    "data": 5
}
```

or

```
{
    "valType": "Integer",
    "data": [2, 3]
}
```

or

```
{
    "valType": "String",
    "data": "value1"
}
```

or

```
{
    "valType": "String",
    "data": ["string1", "string2"]
}
```

value of *data* key is changing. When I tried to map these in Scala with

```
class value {
    var valType: String = _
    var data: Any = _
}
```

using ObjectMapper, it works fine.

But on trying it with lift-json, using class

```
case class value(valType: String, data: Any) {}
```

, it is throwing error

```
Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for data
No information known about type
```

How can I resolve same in lift-json?

Vesrion:
Scala: 2.11
Lift-json: 2.6

Comment: ObjectMapper is running fine, but I want to solve problem with Lift-json

Comment: I'm not familiar with "Lift", but the message said that you can't use type `Any` for `var value` as this will not help the library to know how to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write a custom serializer that parses the "value" field different based on the content of the "valType" field.

How to write a serializer is described in the [Serializing non-supported types](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/#serializing-non-supported-types) section of the lift-json readme.